# XEmacs buffer tabs does not show all buffers

Tags: emacs, xemacs

I am using xemacs for editing. xemacs shows buffer tabs on the top of the editing window. However, my buffer tabs have this strange behavior.

When I switch to cpp file, the buffer tabs show only cpp buffers open. When I shift to a h file (using C-x b), only h files are shown.

How can I make xemacs show all open buffers in buffer tabs all the time ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about xemacs, but with emacs, tabs are shown by tabbar-mode.

And tabbar-mode, by default, groups buffers by major-mode, so in your tabs you only see a group of tabs by same mode.

You can customize it, like they say here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode

```
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function
      (lambda ()
        (list "All"))) ;; code by Peter Barabas
```

Also, there are keystrokes to switch modes in tabs ( M-x tabbar-forward-group, M-x tabbar-backward-group).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not seem to work in xemacs :(
Nor does any other code in the emacswiki page, tabbar not found.

Answer (score 3):

You want to play with customization for the buffers tab. You can get to it by doing *M-x customize*, then *buffers-tab*. There is an option for "Filter Functions", with a default of "select-buffers-tab-buffers-by-mode", which I am guessing is what you want to change. If not, you are sure to find the solution somewhere on that page.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer-tabs in XEmacs have an automatic filtering set up to display groups of similar file-extensions.  I believe you can also filter on other attributes that are discoverable about the buffers in the buffer-list as well.

It is useful when you have many files open, on a small monitor, but gets in the way other times, so you can set the filtering off by, well, here is an excerpt from the XEmacs manual:

"This behavior can be altered by customizing  `buffers-tab-filter-functions'.  Setting this variable to`nil' forces display of all buffers, up to `buffers-tab-max-size' (also customizable).  More complex behavior may be available in 3rd party libraries.  These, and some more rarely customized options, are in the`
buffers-tab' Customize group."